# Itemize without any type of bullets. Why?

Tags: beamer, itemize, bullets

I am trying to elaborate a list with bullets.

But, when I do it, the PDF file is with no bullets at all!

Why?

```
\RequirePackage{flashmovie}
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
      \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
    }
  \vskip0pt%
}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Presentacion.bib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usetheme{Goettingen}

\begin{document}
\justify
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Balance}
\subsection{reacciones}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{frame}{reacciones}
%\begin{frame}{}[plain]
\justify
Las reacciones 
\begin{itemize}
    \item ds
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `enumitem` with beamer

Comment: Happy belayed mole day! https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47303066#47303066

Comment: ahahah @samcarter Contact Avogadro!!!

Comment: Good to hear that it worked!