# Itemize bullets are not shown

Tags: beamer, lists, bullets

I am trying to do a list with itemize but in beamer, the bullets are not shown and I cannot find the reason why.

```
\RequirePackage{flashmovie}
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
      \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}
    }
  \vskip0pt%
}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Presentacion.bib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\title{Titulo}
\subtitle{III-2018}
\institute[Universities of Somewhere and Elsewhere] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
\begin{center}
  \normalsize{Universidad}
\end{center}
}
\date{Bogot\'a}
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Tabla de contenidos}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}
% Let's get started
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \begin{frame}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item prueba
      \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The file that I am working on is shown below:

[image]

Comment: Don't use the `enumitem` package with `beamer`.

Comment: The screenshot you show does not seem to contain a list. Furthermore it can not be produced using your code. If I compile your code, I recieve the following output:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeI6d.png If I remove the `enumitem` package as suggested by Alan Munn, I get the following:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS1CY.png   Please also state the difference to your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456650/134144)  where you were already told to remove `enumitem` from documents using the `beamer` documentclass.

Comment: @leandriis Corrected

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you, To do the same of enumitem, what do you recommend in beamer?

Comment: Just use the built-in `beamer` methods.  They are overlay aware, and can be customized to match the theme. But there's nothing that provides equivalent functionality to `enumitem` because of the extra complexity of `beamer`'s overlay system.

Comment: See also your very own question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456650/itemize-without-any-type-of-bullets-why